# Where does the word Хамовники come from?

Tags: значения, этимология

In Moscow there is a part of the city called Хамовники. What does this word mean, and where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_(%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B)).

From Wikipedia (it's Russian part):

> Слово «хамовники» — от слова «хам», которое с XIV века обозначало льняное полотно (например, просили продать «хаму три локти»).

*«Xамовники» comes from «хам» which was used from the 14th century onward in the meaning "linen fabric" (for example, when someone would buy «хаму три локти»—three ells of linen cloth)*

Comment: Since the question was asked in English, it'd be nice if you provide a short translation/summary of what this says.